# iOS - Web service request after delay

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, delayed-execution, performselector

I have a search bar with a suggestions `UITableView` that gets populated (using JSON services) as the user types. These service calls need to be made after a  delay of 500ms of non-typing. If the user starts to type in this period of 500ms, the current call in the queue needs to be cancelled and the app has to wait another 500ms of non-activity before making another `afterDelay` call. I know I have to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` in this entire situation, but I'm not able to get around with proper conditions. I tried using a bunch of bools but it just getting dirty... Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use an `NSTimer` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. Detect when the text changes in the `UISearchBar` and reset the timer.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    search.delegate = self;

}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [timer invalidate];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(callTheService) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this, assuming you're detecting typing in a `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sendNetworkRequest) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendNetworkRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    return YES;
}

- (void)sendNetworkRequest
{
    // Here immediately send the request
}
```

I like this appraoch to problems like these as it means I don't have to use an `NSTimer` or keep track of any state of whether I'm waiting to see if more text is entered or not. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** Saw you're using a search bar instead. The principle is the same, just put the cancel/perform pairing in the appropriate `UISearchBarDelegate` method.

Comment: I tried this exact same thing before posting this question, but didn't work for me. Anyway, NSTimer worked like a charm and I'm going with it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Ravi No problem! Weird that you had issues with it, it's never let me down. Did it not cancel or not fire?

Comment: It sort of went in an infinite loop. I'm sure there's more to look into, I was looking for more of a straight-forward answer I think :-) Also, NSTimer aligned well with the design of the app...

Comment: `self.performSelector...` does not seem to work with swift.